# Triangulation on a GPS map

Tags: maps, gps

I am looking for an app that can take two points marked on a map and then triangulate a third point with a given distance from those two initial points.

So if I mark A and B on the map and give a 200m distance, it would show me the two points that are ~200m of distance from both A and B (+ - GPS precision).

Requirements for the app:

- It can be online or offline. Offline preferred but not mandatory.
- Android preferred but I won't tag it as Android since if there is a great alternative for iOS that can be useful to others.
- Free or below USD 5.00
- I will physically visit points A and B but if an app can have these points marked on a map and then calculate, that is fine too.

Comment: Any price requirements? Would you actually visit point A and B with GPS enabled to mark it? The "workflow" is not yet clear to me.